# Is there a benefit to pre-checking in online poker?

Tags: online, betting-strategy, tells

I was playing a bit online and I found myself wondering why no one that I have played with ever consistently pre-checks (press the check button before the action gets to them, instantly checking if it is available to that player when the action gets to them) the action.

I was thinking that this could possibly be used to make your opponent think that your hand is very weak in certain circumstances.

Do you ever pre-check action? what are your thoughts on it?

Comment: You have never played with someone that pre-checks?

Comment: no one that consistently pre-checks, edited

Comment: Potentially it could be used to trick someone, but that also assumes they'll be paying attention to your table you do that at and that they themselves aren't playing multiple tables like a lot of people do.

Answer (score 1):

If your opponent thinks a snap-check is weak, it could be adventageous to do it with strong hands. However, giving away fake timing tells can be tricky and it is really hard to balance out. I would recommend to anyone to just be consistent with your timing.